# Limiting Distribution of a Gibbs Distribution

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, markov-chains, monte-carlo

[image]

I know that the Gibbs distribution at a particular state, x, is given by $\frac{e^{-\beta E_i}}{\sum_j e^{-\beta E_j}}$ with $\beta = \frac{1}{T}$, but I do not understand what a limiting distribution means or what $\mu(x)$ is. I know that $\mu(x)$ represents the invariant distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By limiting distribution, they mean the distribution to which the Gibbs distribution converges as you take the limit $T\to0$ or $T\to\infty$.

The limit $T\to\infty$ is a bit easier to take, since in this case $\beta\to0$, so you can calculate the limiting distribution directly by substituting $\beta=0$ into the expression you wrote; you don't need any information about the $E_i$ in this case.

The limit $T\to0$ corresponds to $\beta\to\infty$. To find this, divide your expression through by $\mathrm e^{-\beta E_{\text{min}}}$. Then all exponentials have non-positive exponents, so you can take their limit for $\beta\to\infty$.

That leaves the question which state(s) have minimal energy. Note that your expression decreases strictly monotonically with increasing energy. That allows you to identify the state(s) with minimal energy from the given distribution at finite $T$.

Comment: So, the state with minimal energy is $x=5$ and the $T\to0$ limit for any state $x$ is $\frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: Also, what does $\mu(x)$ tell me, exactly?

Comment: @user151876: Unfortunately wrong on both accounts. The state $x=5$ has the lowest value of $\mu(x)$ at finite $T$. As I wrote, $\mu(x)$ decreases strictly monotonically with increasing energy. Thus, the state with the lowest value of $\mu(x)$ has the highest energy; but you need the lowest energy. Your distribution for the $T\to0$ limit is wrong already because it doesn't sum to $1$. As to your other question, that depends on what you're using this for. If you're using the Gibbs distribution in statistical mechanics, $\mu(x)$ tells you the average occupancy of state $x$ at temperature $T$.